# X-Sendfile and VERY big files on Apache2

Tags: python, apache2, wsgi, x-sendfile

Any filesize over about 4GB is not going to work with the mod_xsendfile for Apache2 (as it sets the content length to a long).

I am willing to rewrite it to support this; however, I can find no documentation on how to set content length from the apache api to something larger than a long and thus serve large files through Apache. I know Apache can do this as it is compiled with Large File Support and is serving the files through the directory index without any issue.

I need to use Apache as I am using WSGI. I do not want to use FastCGI or switch off Apache2 for various reasons I do not feel like getting into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location of the Beta for [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/beta/) on Apache2

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the answer. Use the BETA version provided. It seems to fix this issue.